# How can I keep elements moving with the page as it resizes maintaing their position in relation to background image?

Tags: html, css

I have a page with a responsive background image. I have a text field I want to always maintain it's position in relation to a part of the background image's design. There's a drawing of a cat's paw in the background image that I will have a div overlaying. This div will have an event handler. What I need help with though, is getting the text field to keep it's position in relation to the paw drawing in the background image when resizing height or width or both. Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9ra5h/1/ 
Would appreciate your help.

```
<body>
<div id="wrapcontent">
<div id="bannerads">
</div>
<div id="txtFields" style="
height: 121px;
top: 280px;
width:60%;
position: relative;
left: 15%;">

<textarea id="bottomtxt" class="topcoat-textarea unselectable" rows="6" cols="36" placeholder=""></textarea>    
<div onclick="getAnswer();" id="submitbtn" class="unselectable"></div>  
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

more or less like this: http://jsfiddle.net/9ra5h/3/??

you have to use:

```
position: fixed;
```

then use a % for both left and top (or right and bottom) and experiment with the positioning till you find what you are looking for.